# Populating a Pandas dataframe where index and column are values of another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with columns ['ID', 'DATE', 'VALUE']. The way that the data I am sourcing comes in, I have many duplicate IDs, each of which has a duplicate price--so, for instance, the frame will come in with

```
ID  Date   Value
a  1/1/17    2
a  1/2/17    3
a  1/3/17    4
b  1/1/17    5
b  1/2/17    6
b  1/2/17    7
```

I have made a frame where the date is the index, and unique IDs are the columns, via

```
ID = list(set(df['ID']))
DATE = list(set(df['DATE']))
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ID, index = DATE).sort()
```

I now want to retrieve the Value from df, and place it so that newdf[DATE][ID] matches up with the those indices from df, and I can't figure out how to cast those without some onerous for loops--is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We using `combine_first`+`pivot_table`

```
newdf.combine_first(pd.pivot_table(df,index='Date',columns='ID',values='Value',aggfunc='sum'))
Out[442]: 
          a     b
1/1/17  2.0   5.0
1/2/17  3.0  13.0
1/3/17  4.0   NaN
```

Comment: This works brilliantly! I think everything else I can get by merging, but this is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelSchweitzer YW~ :-) happy coding

Comment: Nice answer Wen.  But why use `combine_first`?  It looks like we get the desired result from the `pivot_table()`.

Comment: @andrew_reece I think this is just coincidence, since he want to lookup the value for newdf, it all depend on how newdf created..